# How to create a pure redirect HTTP site under Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-static-website-hosting

I have a static website `foo.example.com` that contains a list of pages (several hundreds). I want to migrate this website to another static website, as subfolder `www.example.com/foo`. At this point, I have a list of URLs from `foo.example.com` and their associated URLs under `www.example.com/foo`. The mapping is irregular and accidental. There is no regex possible to rewrite the old URLs into the new ones, it has to be hard-coded.

I am seeking a service available under Azure to "bind" those old URLs with HTTP redirects pointing to the new URLs. Ideally, I would be looking to a serverless solution, or even better a fully static solution. What would work in this case? I am looking for something as maintainable as possible as the original list of URLs will not change in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Azure Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview) would be your best here if you are willing to move the current `www.example.com` website behind Front Door as well.

With this, you can define [URL Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite?pivots=front-door-standard-premium) rules to rewrite `/foo` requests to go to `foo.example.com` (or the corresponding backend).

Answer (score 0):

A cheaper approach is to use App Service, which could be FREE. See [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/zhiliang_xus_blog/build-a-google-reverse-proxy-site-on-azure-web-app-in-less-than-3-minutes).

Comment: This approach is logically equivalent to introduce a custom ASP.NET webapp, which is precisely what I am trying to avoid. The problem is not the hosting cost, but the maintenance cost.